# Algorithms. Single source shortest paths. Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithm

How do I find all possible shortest paths from a source vertex to more than one destination, such that the edge-weights in the shortest paths tree are in decreasing order of weights?

Comment: You mentioned the Dijkstra'a algorithm. Did you get the information (by whom ?) that this algorithm is suitable in this case, or is that a guess ?

Comment: It's just a guess, as there are no negative weights allowed in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume here a strict decreasing of the weights among a path.

This implies that when considering a given path, we have to memorize/consider not only the corresponding total distance, but also the value of the last weight.

Therefore, at a given node, we have to memorize different possible paths, i.e. different pairs (total distance, last weight), and not only one. This does not not mean that all combinations must be memorized. For example, if we have two paths (13,2) and (15,2), only (13,2) is kept. In the same spirit, if we get (10,3) and (10,2), only (10,3) must be kept.

This is illustrated in figure hereafter, hopefully self explaining. I assume directed edges here.

```
     3                     4                      2
A(3,3) -->C (6,2), (11,5)---->D (11,4), (13,3) ------>F (13,2)
|         |                   |                      NB: (15,2) skipped
|3        |5                  |3
|         |             4     |
S ------->B (6,6)------------>E (10, 4)
    6
```

In practice, existing short path finding algorithms should be adapted for that. My understanding is that for example the Floyd–Warshall algorithm
can be adapted for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
The case is that we didn't cover Floyd-Warshall in our course. And it kind of makes everything more complicated. Can you, please, explain for example why the edge (A,S) is not directed?

Comment: I simply mentioned FW algorithm because it is the most straightforward one, in my opinion the one that can be most easily adapted. I have a problem with the Dijkstra's algorithm, because of the difficulty to define an order relationship with pairs of numbers. Which algorithms did you learn in course? AS is directed: S->A, difficult to represent it with this kind of figure

Comment: Bellman-Ford could be adapted in my understanding. Maybe DAG too, not sure

Comment: Thank you a lot. Very grateful for the help.

Comment: Please let us know if you succeed implementing it